# How to disable azure auto-acknowledgement alerts after the issue is being resolved?

Tags: azure

I want to be notified only when the issue occure/ alert condition met. but I am recieving extra alerts after the issue is resolved. it is unnessary filling up my mail box and making the process more time taking. is there any way to avoid Resolved issue acknowledgement alerts. Thanks for your help.

I have a Bicep code that create alerts. Not sure what setting needs to be updated in order to achieve the above result as mentioned.

```
 "parameters": {
        "logAlerts": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "alertName": "Some Alert",
                    "description": "Some alert Description",
                    "enabled": true,
                    "severity": 2,
                    "scopes": [
                        "/Subscription"
                    ],
                    "autoMitigate": true,
                    "targetResourceType": [
                        "microsoft.insights/components"
                    ],
                    "evaluationFrequency": "PT15M",
                    "windowSize": "PT30M",
                    "criteria": {
                        "allOf": [
                            {
                                "query": "",
                                "timeAggregation": "Count",
                                "dimensions": [],
                                "operator": "GreaterThanOrEqual",
                                "threshold": 100,
                                "failingPeriods": {
                                    "numberOfEvaluationPeriods": 1,
                                    "minFailingPeriodsToAlert": 1
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "actions": {
                        "actionGroups": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "customProperties": {}
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Try to change the `"autoMitigate": true` to `false`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-troubleshoot-metric reference from FAQ

Answer (score 0):

After a workaround on the issue, I found two approaches to stop receiving alerts once the issue got resolved but fire the same alert condition on the remaining ones.

***Approach-1:***

Using Alert processing rules:

You can create an alert processing rule by going to
`Monitor >> Alerts >> Alert Processing rules`.

[image]

Once you click on it, it prompts you to select a `scope` and then below page will be redirected.

Now choose `rule type` as `suppress notifications`, then create an alert processing rule to meet your requirement.

[image]

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-processing-rules?tabs=powershell) for more relevant information.

You can also achieve the same functionality using
`Set-AzAlertProcessingRule` PowerShell command as shown below.

[image]

***Approach-2:***

According to the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-troubleshoot-metric#metric-alert-fired-when-it-shouldnt-have) you can also stop receiving alerts by setting `autoMitigate` property to `false` using ARM templates (Bicep/ARM) as shown below.

```bash
"logAlerts": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "alertName": "Some Alert",
                    "description": "Some alert Description",
                    "enabled": true,
                    "severity": 2,
                    "scopes": [
                        "/Subscription"
                    ],
                    "autoMitigate": false,
                    "targetResourceType": [
                        "microsoft.insights/components"
                    ]
```